# Paste one column to all other columns if they are not NA

Tags: r, dataframe

My problem is that I have a **dataframe** of 5 columns, where 4 columns contain names and 1 contain status. For instance

```
   X1       X2      X3       X4       X5
1 name1     NA     name3     NA     active   
2 name1   name2     NA      name4   inactive
3 NA      name2    name3    name4   unknown
4 name1   name2     NA       NA     inactive
5 name1   name2    name3    name4   unknown
```

What I would like to do is to alternate `col X5` in between of each X1, X2, X3 and X4 and paste them together with an underscore (`name1_active`, `name2_inactive`) without taking into consideration the `NA` cases.

```
   X1      X5       X2      X5        X3      X5       X4       X5
1 name1  active     NA      NA      name3   active     NA       NA   
2 name1  inactive  name2  inactive   NA       NA      name4   inactive
3 NA       NA      name2  unknown   name3   unknown   name4   unknown
4 name1  inactive  name2  inactive   NA       NA       NA       NA
5 name1  unknown   name2  unknown   name3   unknown   name4   unknown
```

output:

```
       X1             X2                X3             X4 
1 name1_active        NA           name3_active        NA     
2 name1_inactive  name2_inactive        NA         name4_inactive
3     NA          name2_unknown    name3_unknown   name4_unknown
4 name1_inactive  name2_inactive        NA             NA   
5 name1_unknown   name2_unknown    name3_unknown   name4_unknown
```

Comment: What do you mean by alternating? Why is there an inactive in the second row for X2?

Comment: I want to paste `x5` as it is next to each `x#` but without taking in consideration the `NA` cases.

Comment: the first dataset is my input data. It comes like that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
d <- read.table(text = "X1       X2      X3       X4       X5
1 name1     NA     name3     NA     active   
2 name1   name2     NA      name4   inactive
3 NA      name2    name3    name4   unknown
4 name1   name2     NA       NA     inactive
5 name1   name2    name3    name4   unknown", header = TRUE)

as.data.frame(lapply(d[, 1:4], function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), NA, paste(x, d$X5, sep = "_"))))
#              X1             X2            X3             X4
#1   name1_active           <NA>  name3_active           <NA>
#2 name1_inactive name2_inactive          <NA> name4_inactive
#3           <NA>  name2_unknown name3_unknown  name4_unknown
#4 name1_inactive name2_inactive          <NA>           <NA>
#5  name1_unknown  name2_unknown name3_unknown  name4_unknown
```

Answer (score 4):

This is similar to r.user.05apr's answer, but I want to show that we can use `lapply` to directly loop through and replace the columns in the original data frame.

```
dat[, paste0("X", 1:4)] <- lapply(dat[, paste0("X", 1:4)], function(x){
  ifelse(!is.na(x), paste(x, dat$X5, sep = "_"), x)
})

dat$X5 <- NULL

dat
#               X1             X2            X3             X4
# 1   name1_active           <NA>  name3_active           <NA>
# 2 name1_inactive name2_inactive          <NA> name4_inactive
# 3           <NA>  name2_unknown name3_unknown  name4_unknown
# 4 name1_inactive name2_inactive          <NA>           <NA>
# 5  name1_unknown  name2_unknown name3_unknown  name4_unknown
```

We can also use `mutate_at` from the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-X5), funs(ifelse(!is.na(.), paste(., X5, sep = "_"), .))) %>%
  select(-X5)
dat2
#               X1             X2            X3             X4
# 1   name1_active           <NA>  name3_active           <NA>
# 2 name1_inactive name2_inactive          <NA> name4_inactive
# 3           <NA>  name2_unknown name3_unknown  name4_unknown
# 4 name1_inactive name2_inactive          <NA>           <NA>
# 5  name1_unknown  name2_unknown name3_unknown  name4_unknown
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "   X1       X2      X3       X4       X5
1 name1     NA     name3     NA     active   
                  2 name1   name2     NA      name4   inactive
                  3 NA      name2    name3    name4   unknown
                  4 name1   name2     NA       NA     inactive
                  5 name1   name2    name3    name4   unknown",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll throw a `purrr` + `stringr`-solution in the pot ;)

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

map_df(my_data[, 1:4], ~ str_c(.x, "_", my_data$X5))

# A tibble: 5 x 4
#   X1             X2             X3            X4            
#   <chr>          <chr>          <chr>         <chr>         
# 1 name1_active   NA             name3_active  NA            
# 2 name1_inactive name2_inactive NA            name4_inactive
# 3 NA             name2_unknown  name3_unknown name4_unknown 
# 4 name1_inactive name2_inactive NA            NA            
# 5 name1_unknown  name2_unknown  name3_unknown name4_unknown
```

`map_df` automatically returns a `tibble` and with `str_c` the missing values are "infectious".

Answer (score 1):

My solution using `apply`:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c('a1', 'a2', 'a3'))
df$B <- c('b1', 'b2', 'b3')
df$C <- c('c1', 'c2', 'c3')
df$STATUS <- c('OK', 'BAD', 'OK')

df1 <- apply(df[,1:(ncol(df)-1)], 2, function(X) {
  X <- paste0(X, "_", df$STATUS)
})
df1
```

With result:

```
     A        B        C       
[1,] "a1_OK"  "b1_OK"  "c1_OK" 
[2,] "a2_BAD" "b2_BAD" "c2_BAD"
[3,] "a3_OK"  "b3_OK"  "c3_OK"
```

Comment: No need to create your own example. Feel free to use my example code to recreate OP's example.

Comment: @www I didn't see it before posting. It can be adapted for OP, so if he chooses it, he can personalize it slightly.

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr and if I understood correctly in a brute force kind of way:
(I assume you want to keep the cases with NA_something and something_NA but not NA_NA)

```
df2 <- df %>%
    mutate(X1 = paste(X1,X5,sep="_")) %>%
    mutate(X1 = ifelse(X1 %in% c("NA_NA"),NA,X1)) %>%
    mutate(X2 = paste(X2,X5,sep="_")) %>%
    mutate(X2 = ifelse(X2 %in% c("NA_NA"),NA,X2)) %>%
    mutate(X3 = paste(X3,X5,sep="_")) %>%
    mutate(X3 = ifelse(X3 %in% c("NA_NA"),NA,X3) %>%
    mutate(X4 = paste(X4,X5,sep="_")) %>%
    mutate(X4 = ifelse(X4 %in% c("NA_NA"),NA,X4)) %>%
    select(-X5)
```

Comment: You can use `mutate_at` to simplify your code. Please see the updates in my post as an example.

Comment: Indeed not the best for a large number of columns . The question was on 5 columns, so the answer is adapted, "brute force". I dont see why one would downgrade that answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lapply` directly if you assign to `d[]` instead of `d`:

```
d[] <- lapply(d, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), NA, paste(x,d$X5, sep="_")))
# or, excluding the 5th col
d[,-5] <- lapply(d[,-5], function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), NA, paste(x,d$X5, sep="_")))
```

Or if you do not want to overwrite the values in `d`, you can use the fancy-looking `"[<-"` approach:

```
"[<-"(d,,-5, lapply(d[,-5], function(.) ifelse(is.na(.), NA, paste(., d$X5, sep="_"))))
# notice two commas with nothing in between - not a typo
```

Finally, an `environment()`-friendly solution:

```
within(d, 
       list2env(
        lapply(d, 
               function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), NA, paste(x,X5, sep="_"))), 
        environment()))
```